# Como abrir o MainPage.axml de um Xamarin Project no modo Designer?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

Então, recentemente baixei o Visual Studio 2017 e me deparei com o Aplicativo Multiplataforma (Xamarim.Forms ou Nativo), quando crio-o é gerado 4 projetos. O `App1; App1.Droid; App1.IOS; App1.UWP (Universal Windows Plataform)`.

Não entendo muito bem de Xamarin, mas imagino que o que eu fizer no projeto App1 será compilado para todas as outras plataformas, no entanto gostaria de abrir o MainPage.axml e o App.axml no modo designer para poder editar visualmente, mas só consigo fazer isso com o MainPage.axml e App.axml do projeto para UWP. Gostaria de saber como abro os arquivos do projeto principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App.xaml ("design") e App.cs (code behind)` é apenas um arquivo digamos 'de partida' em projetos `Xamarin-Forms`.

O arquivo (`App.xaml`) não contem (diretamente) nada relacionado a parte de `UI`, digo diretamente porque nele pode conter configurações de estilos de design, cor da fonte por exemplo, etc. Resumindo essa `view` não tem a função de interagir com o usuário.

Uma das funções do arquivo (`App.cs`) é definir a página inicial do aplicativo dentre outras, para mais detalhes consulte: [App Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/)

Modo design ainda não existe o que torna o desenvolvimento cansativo já que para verificar alteração na *UI* é necessário rodar aplicação, porém, conheço duas ferramentas que tornam essa tarefa menos dolorosa:

1. **Xamarin.Forms Previewer** Opção `View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. **Gorilla Player** Acho mais completo pois tem melhor suporte no reconhecimento do `Xaml`. É mais complicado para configurar (necessário instalar apk) mas vale a pena. 
   [Baixar Versão para VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UXDivers.GorillaPlayerVisualStudioAddin)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fontes:**
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/
https://elbruno.com/2016/01/28/xamarin-live-preview-of-xaml-in-xamarinforms-using-gorillaplayer-in-visualstudio/

Comment: Ainda não testei o Xamarin Previewer, mas tenho ouvido falar que só funcionou no MS Build.

Comment: Instalei recentemente o VS 2017 e funcionou, porém ainda deixa a desejar, por exemplo, coloquei uma imagem de fundo e não reconheceu. Já no Gorilla Player funcionou perfeito.

Answer (score 3):

**Respondendo a sua dúvida/citação:**

Sim, resumindo, em Xamarin.Forms você escreve o layout (View) das suas telas e a lógica da aplicação apenas uma vez (no seu caso, dentro do App1) e o layout nativo para as outras plataformas é gerado (compilado) automaticamente. É possível também alterar individualmente o layout e modificar o comportamento individual de cada plataforma caso queira algo mais específico.

**Agora vamos a resposta para a sua pergunta:**

Não há ainda um Designer disponível para as páginas XAML do Xamarin Forms. Você deve fazer tudo na "mão". Para ver o resultado você deve executar o aplicativo no emulador desejado ou no seu celular.

Essa informação pode ser encontrada na página dos conceitos básicos do Xamarin.Forms XAML: [Xamarin.Forms XAML](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/)

Traduzindo o que está escrito lá:

> Não há ainda um editor visual para o XAML gerado nas aplicações Xamarin.Forms, então todo o XAML deve ser escrito a mão.